# How to achieve notch curve in bottomnavigationbar flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a BottomNavigationBar like below image:

[image: BottomNavigationBar]

But i want to achieve a curve in the marked corner similar to the below image:

[image: this is what i want to achieve here]

**Here is my code:**

> Code for the bottomNavigationBar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 7, 
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        color: Color(0xff1c1f26),
        shape: AutomaticNotchedShape(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(14),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(14),
          )),
        ), //10
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 60,
        )),
```

> Code for the Floationgactionbutton:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17))), //17
      onPressed: () {
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
    ),
```

How can I achieve that curve there?

Answer (score 0):

use `CircularNotchedRectangle` instead of `AutomaticNotchedShape`

Comment: This does not help bro. it gives me a rounded curve which i didnt need. I need a square curve but only corners are round.

Comment: Hello, if you want to control it all, you can use package to make your shape .

Comment: can you specify the name. which package should i use to achieve this?